# ReactJS - Rending Map Function with Nested Array in Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out how to `map` a nested array in my prop and also determine if there is a better, best practice, way to split out this logic into a separate component. I thought I had followed the correct approach below, but receive an error at my opening `{` for the start of the nested `map` method.

**Error message:**

```
ERROR in ./public/components/app/comment-box/comment.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (46:12)

  44 |         <div>
  45 |         { props.records.map((record, index) => <RecordCard {...record} />
> 46 |             {
     |             ^
  47 |                 { record.record_comments.map((comment, i) =>
```

**Code:**

```
  //GET /api/test and set to state
    class RecordsFeedContainer extends React.Component{
        constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);
            this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {records: []};
        }

        fetchList() {
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
                .then(res => {
                    return res.json();
                })  
                .then(data => {
                    this.setState({ records: data });
                })
                .bind(this)  
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.fetchList();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                <h2>Records List</h2>
                <ul>
                <RecordsFeed {...this.state} />
                </ul>
                </div>
            )
        }
    };

    //Loop through JSON and component
    const RecordsFeed = props => {
            return (
            <div>
            { props.records.map((record, index) => <RecordCard {...record} />
                {
                    { record.record_comments.map((comment, i) => <Comments {...comment} />)}
                }
            )}
            </div>
            )
    }
```

Comment: Show sample of your data.Whats comes from  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX `props.records.map((record, index) => <RecordCard {...record} />`

is turned into

```
props.records.map((record, index) => {
    return React.createElement(RecordCard, ...record);
}
```

Your code would be

```
props.records.map((record, index) => {
    return React.createElement(RecordCard, ...record) { { record.record_comments.map...;
}
```

I'm guessing comments should be inside the cards, right?
So then you could do this instead:

```
{ props.records.map((record, index) => {
    return (
        <RecordCard {...record}>
            { record.record_comments.map((comment, i) => <Comments {...comment} /> )}
        </RecordCard>
    );
} )}
```

Then inside `RecordCard` you would add `{this.props.children}` somewhere in it's `render` method's returned JSX.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. I wasn't aware of the JSX ability to wrap objects within the `<RecordCard>`. The last part of your answer I have a few additional questions at the moment. It appears I'm accessing the array incorrectly. `(<RecordCard>, <Comments>)` is triggering the `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop` error. `const Comments = props => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div id={props.recordCommentId}>
            <h4>{props.comment}</h4>
            <p>{props.recordCommentId}</p>
        </div>
    )
}`

Comment: Yes, when returning lists/arrays React can optimise DOM merging if you assign each element a unique meaningfull key (think "user ID" not "array index"). What you need to do is add a key attribute along the id one on each comment. key={props.recordCommentId} will do the trick.